# .JS File using @url.action in Ajax Url

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-4

I been trying to use `@Url.Action` inside Ajax `url` in another external `.JS` file but unfortunately i got no luck.

Here's my Code:

```
 $.ajax({
      type: 'post',
      url: "@Url.Action("ClearData","Home")",
      success: function () {

       }
     });
```

This Code working only inside the View itself but not in `Javascript externally`.
Iv'e been searched some possible solution but it seems different than this.

Is there any alternative way to use `@Url.Action` in another `.Js` File?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`@Url.Action()` is razor (server side) code and is not parsed in external files. Options include

Declaring a global variable in the main file, say

```
var url = @Url.Action("ClearData","Home");
```

and then in the external script use `url: url` in the ajax call

Including a `data-` attribute in the element your handling, for example if its a button click event, then

```
<button data-url="@Url.Action("ClearData","Home")" id="mybutton">
```

and then reading that value in the external file, for example

```
$('#mybutton').click(function() {
    var url = $(this).data('url');
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        ....
```

Comment: Thanks @Stephen it's working fine.. I am using an Image Control change your button as img and bring the image which is selected by any user  into an Image Control itself.

Comment: @user3559349 I don't know whether I understood you correctly, but I didn't need to declare a global variable in the main file. Once I added the `data-` attribute in the element I am handling and then read the value in the external file as you said `var url = $(this).data('url');`, it was working fine. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @user3559349 Thanks you very much
I used your solution but I used an hidden field, like that : `<input type="hidden" data-url="@Url.Action("Action", "Controller")" id="hidUrl">` and call it from jquery `var url = $('#hidUrl').data('url');`. its work perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

if your js code inside view

```
$.ajax({
      type: 'post',
      url: "@Url.Action("ClearData","Home")",
      success: function () {

       }
     });
```

this is work

when js code is an separate (external file)
`@Url.Action("ClearData","Home")` is not work ,
this case you have to write total url or folder path

Answer (score 0):

You can create a partial view, then inside this view are just list of hidden fields
such as

```
@Html.Hidden("ActionName", @Url.Action("ActionName", "Controller"))
```

which generates this

```
<input id="ActionName" name="ActionName" type="hidden" value="/controller/ActionName">
```

then you can call it like

```
  var urlAction = $('#ActioName').val();
```

or you can create a js function like what I did

```
 function ActionCaller(actionName)
 {
    return $('#' + actionName).val();
 }

 var action = ActionCaller(ActionName);
```