# ajax returns an html code instead of returning the response of the request to a url, in mvc 3

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a problem when trying to make a request to a url created from mvc, this request is made to an actionresult of a controller, when I am in home ajax if it finds the address, but when I am in a site of my specific system , that is, I am in a section where the url is larger due to other parameters that are in the url, for example in a user profile, there ajax instead of finding the url that is linked to an actionresult return the html page, that is, return the html code, here are my codes

```
function guardarCalificacion(newidp, ratingp)
{
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'saveRating',
        data: {
            newid: newidp,
            rating: ratingp

        },
        beforeSend: function () {



        },
        success: function (data)
        {
            alert(data);
        },
        error: function ()
        { },
        complete: function ()
        { }

    });



}
```

**and there are the route**

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "saveRating",
            "saveRating/{newid}/{rating}",
            new { controller = "Home", action = "SaveRating", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

**in this url if it runs well**

```
http://localhost:49439/Home/index
```

**but in this it is not executed**

```
http://localhost:49439/new/128/busqueda-numero-29
```

**and finally the actionresult**

```
 public ActionResult SaveRating(int newid, int rating)
    {

        return Content(Methods.saveRating(newid, rating).ToString());
    }
```

Comment: Always use the `Url.Action()` method to ensure your url's are generated correctly = `url: '@Url.Action("saveRating")',`

Comment: first, sorry for my bad english and I did what you suggested and I get this answer  @Url.Action(%22saveRating%22) Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Then I assume that script is in an external file. Either move it into you view, or assign the url in the view so that it can be passed to your external script

Comment: yes, it is an external script, you do not have any article in hand to better understand what you suggested to me

Comment: Refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46639849/js-file-using-url-action-in-ajax-url/46640007#46640007) for a couple of options

Comment: that's work! thanks very much

Comment: Try to use full path in your ajax `url : '/saveRating'`, you are using relative URL that is why it works from main page but not from other pages.

Comment: Well, I had already tried several times what you suggest and it did not work out, in other url that I have if it works but in that no, I broke my head trying to find the answer
: 49439 / saveRating Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: use `\saveRating`, this makes browser take absolute path.