# Ajax post to controller not found

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have the following JavaScript:

```
function saveAvatar() {
    var img = $('#preview-pane .preview-container img');
    $('#avatar-crop-box button').addClass('disabled');
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: App.url + "/Save",
        traditional: true,
        data: {
            width: img.css('width'),
            height: img.css('height'),
            marginLeft: img.css('marginLeft'),
            marginTop: img.css('marginTop'),
            fileName: img.attr('src'),
            userId: this.userId
        }
    }).done(function (data) {
        if (data.success === true) {
            if (!keepCropBox) {
                $('#avatar-crop-box').addClass('hidden');
                location.reload();
            }
        } else {
            alert(data.errorMessage)
        }
    }).fail(function (e) {
        alert('Cannot upload avatar at this time');
    });
}
```

Here is my save method:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> Save(string marginTop, string marginLeft, string height, string width, string fileName, int userId)
{
    var image = ImageHelper.Save(marginTop, marginLeft, height, width, fileName);

    if(image != "error")
    {
        var savedProfilePicture = await userService.SaveProfilePicture(image, userId);

        if (savedProfilePicture > 0)
        {
            return Json(new { success = true, avatarFileLocation = image });
        }
    }

    return Json(new { success = false, errorMessage = "Could not save profile picture" });
}
```

This works fine when I run the project on my local machine and when the App.url is set to http://localhost:1234/Home

But when I deploy the project to a server, and the App.url becomes: `http://project-on-another-machine.com/Home`. It's not working with the Save-method. I'm always getting a 404 not found.

I have other method that works fine, but not this particular Save-method. Why is this?

Comment: @ViRuSTriNiTy: Read my question again. When I run the project on my machine, It's set to http://localhost:1234/Home, and when It's deployd on the other machine, it's set to http://project-on-another-machine.com/Home,

Comment: Just change the Url to "/ControllerName/Save".

Comment: Always use `Url.Action()` to generate the correct url - `url: '@Url.Action("Save", "Home")',`

Comment: @StephenMuecke: That don't seem to work in my app.js-file?

Comment: Again. My other methods in my controller works just fine. This particular one don't work when I deploy to a other machine.

Comment: @Bryan you could inject it in as an attribute on an element on your page and then look it up using javascript.

Comment: @RMH: yeah, I can. But as I said, the other methods in my controller works just fine. But not this one.

Comment: If its in an external file, then you need to use `var url = '@Url.Action("Save", "Home")';` in the main view and pass it to the external file (`url: url,`)

Comment: @Bryan does the other method load in the same way as the above? So the App.Url + a string? Additionally, does it also do a post?

Comment: Alternatively assign it to a `data-` attribute of the element triggering that script - refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46639849/js-file-using-url-action-in-ajax-url/46640007#46640007) for an example

Answer (score 0):

In your view add the value of URL in a global variable like this

```
<script>
    var params["saveUrl"] = "@Action("Save","Home")";
</script>
```

and then use this variable in your js file to access the action method.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: params["saveUrl"],
    ...
```

Comment: @Nithesh: But I should I do this when It's working just fine with my other methods?

Comment: @Bryan yes, you should *always* do this (use `@Url.Action`)

Answer (score 0):

The `Url` should be `url: "/Home/Save/"`

```
function saveAvatar() {
    var img = $('#preview-pane .preview-container img');
    $('#avatar-crop-box button').addClass('disabled');
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Home/Save",
        traditional: true,
        data: {
            width: img.css('width'),
            height: img.css('height'),
            marginLeft: img.css('marginLeft'),
            marginTop: img.css('marginTop'),
            fileName: img.attr('src'),
            userId: this.userId
        }
    }).done(function (data) {
        if (data.success === true) {
            if (!keepCropBox) {
                $('#avatar-crop-box').addClass('hidden');
                location.reload();
            }
        } else {
            alert(data.errorMessage)
        }
    }).fail(function (e) {
        alert('Cannot upload avatar at this time');
    });
}
```